# What are the best practices regarding cryptography when different platforms are in concern?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

The question is, what could be the most preferable approach one can follow while working with encryption and decryption when dealing with different platforms.

As per my knowledge , whenever one wants to work with such scenarios , he/she has to take certain things into account. Like say,

1. Encryption/decryption Algorithm
2. Padding pattern
3. Character Encoding at both sides
4. Cipher key and block sizes

Certainly ,the Encryption/Decryption algorithm one wants to use must be same at both the sides and i guess i can say the same thing about remaining three things.

Please suggest me the steps to follow while i work with following or similar scenarios.

1. Encrypting in c & decrypting in java
2. Encrypting in php & decrypting in java

Comment: Hi Puru, welcome to Stack Overflow, please edit your question so you highlight an actual question. Simply asking people to share knowledge invites discussion, which puts your question in danger of being closed by the community as not constructive. Use this [edit] link to modify your post and ask a more specific question about what you don't understand. Good luck! :)

Comment: thanks jmort253. I've done the edits as you suggested .

Comment: Do you want just symmetric encryption or asymmetric encryption (e.g. RSA) as well? The former handles bytes (so big endian/little endian is not important for the ciphertext. The other uses integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very important aspect for good interoperability is standard compliance.

Good cryptographic standards come with test vectors. If the two ends implement the same specification and the relevant test cases have been verified, there are much higher chances they will successfully talk to each other.

For instance, let's say you need to derive an AES key from a password. If you use openssl, you may be tempted to use the common `EVP_BytesToKey` function. Unfortunately, that is not a standard derivation algorithm and you will find yourself in troubles if at the other end you don't have openssl too. Using a standard like PBKDF2 is better, because you have a clear, well-known, and widespread specification for it ([RFC2898](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt)) that most libraries implement.

Unfortunately, cryptographic standards tend to focus on the primitives only and it is often necessary to graft together several ones. The "grafting" may prove to be the area where interoperability falls apart. For that reason, I suggest to use the widest possible standardized algorithm, even at the cost of some extra complexity.

For instance, if you want to encrypt something, it would be good to choose a standard authenticated mode like CCM (defined - amongst others - in [RFC3610](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3610)). In one go you obtain interoperability for:

- Encryption
- Authentication
- Padding
- Delivery of IV

Answer (score 1):

Try and use container formats, such as CMS if you are really interested in interoperability. It deploys BER/DER encoded ASN.1, which is a binary encoding of a message structure (similar to XML which is a textual encoding of a message). Unfortunately not all platforms contain such message formats, but if they are supported you can be reasonably sure that they can encode / decode messages.

PHP is tricky, it either relies on openssl wrappers or the horrible mcrypt libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I would add byte ordering (little endian versus big endian for numbers) but, as long as you pick the same algorithm (and parameters) and data formats, what is encrypted on one platform should be decryptable on the other and vice versa. This is how SSL works today, for example.